Sending Html table via Outlook using python
I am trying to display a html table in Outlook body using python but I am unable to display.
Html ='{data}'
I am using above line in python variable data contains the html table content.
Only the data is getting displayed in email body not data or table is getting displayed.
I am using dynamic data.
Can anyone please advise on this.
Subash

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?
